# Spark 2.0 - Split Dataframe into subDataframes without using createOrReplaceTempView

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF as show below , I need to convert this into sub-Dataframes without using createOrReplaceTempView (and doing sub-queries in sql) as the sub-Dataframes will be used for performing multiple left joins with Master Table

I tried listvaluesDF.createOrReplaceTempView("listvaluesDF") &&  var dfYear = spark.sql("select key, value from listvaluesDF where internal = 'year'"), but when I do explain its creating a View which can conflict when doing big left join

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+
|                 key|               value|        internal|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+
|         accessories|   D31 - Accessories|  wmt0Department|
|         annualEvent|        Annual Event|       wmt0Event|
|             apparel|             Apparel|         wmt0SBU|
|          automotive|    D10 - Automotive|  wmt0Department|
|              baking|              baking|wmt0DeptCategory|
|              baking|              Baking|      seasonType|
|              baking|              Baking|wmt0DeptCategory|
|       bathandShower|D20 - Bath and Sh...|  wmt0Department|
|             bedding|       D22 - Bedding|  wmt0Department|
|               betty|               Betty|wmt0DeptCategory|
|          boxedCards|         Boxed Cards|wmt0DeptCategory|
|            boyswear|            Boyswear|wmt0DeptCategory|
|            boyswear|      D24 - Boyswear|  wmt0Department|
|        buildaBasket|      Build a Basket|wmt0DeptCategory|
|  camerasAndSupplies|D06 - Cameras & S...|  wmt0Department|
|       cardsAndGifts|       Cards & Gifts|      seasonType|
|       cardsAndGifts|       Cards & Gifts|wmt0DeptCategory|
|             carving|             Carving|wmt0DeptCategory|
|         celebration|   D67 - Celebration|  wmt0Department|
|      chineseNewYear|    Chinese New Year|      seasonType|
|           christmas|           Christmas|      seasonType|
|         cookandDine| D14 - Cook and Dine|  wmt0Department|
|            costumes|            Costumes|wmt0DeptCategory|
|              crafts|        D44 - Crafts|  wmt0Department|
|               decor|               Décor|wmt0DeptCategory|
|    decortiveGarland|Decorative Wreath...|wmt0DeptCategory|
|          dotcomOnly|         Dotcom Only|  wmt0DotcomOnly|
|             dressUp|            Dress Up|wmt0DeptCategory|
|              easter|              Easter|      seasonType|
|         electronics|   D72 - Electronics|  wmt0Department|
|       entertainment|       Entertainment|         wmt0SBU|
|                fall|           S3 - Fall|      seasonType|
|           fallGMPad|         Fall GM Pad|       wmt0Event|
|         fallModular|        Fall Modular|      seasonType|
|         familySocks|  D27 - Family Socks|  wmt0Department|
|         familySocks|        Family Socks|wmt0DeptCategory|
|          fathersDay|        Father's Day|      seasonType|
|             feature|             Feature|       wmt0Event|
|           featureQ1|          Feature Q1|      seasonType|
|           featureQ2|          Feature Q2|      seasonType|
|           featureQ3|          Feature Q3|      seasonType|
|           featureQ4|          Feature Q4|      seasonType|
|      featureSeason1|    Feature Season 1|      seasonType|
|      featureSeason2|    Feature Season 2|      seasonType|
|      featureSeason3|    Feature Season 3|      seasonType|
|      featureSeason4|    Feature Season 4|      seasonType|
|           firstHalf|     H1 – First Half|      seasonType|
```

Comment: 'dfYear = listvaluesDf.select('key, 'value).where('internal.equals("year")) drYear.show() ' have you tried that?

Comment: Let me try that, meanwhile the above problem looks like product issue -- issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25150

Comment: scala> val dfTempYear =  listvaluesDF.select('key, 'value).where('internal.equals("year"))
<console>:25: error: overloaded method value where with alternatives:
  (conditionExpr: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 cannot be applied to (Boolean)
       val dfTempYear =  listvaluesDF.select('key, 'value).where('internal.equals("year"))

Comment: This worked - val dfTempYear =  listvaluesDF.filter($"internal" === "year").select('key, 'value), But will try the main left join and let you know @chlebek

Comment: No Luck, Spark is linking the new subset DF to original Lineage

Comment: did you call dfTempYear.show() after creating this df? it could help

Comment: Tried, Nope, Let me try Cache(), Persist()

Comment: No Luck in cache, persist, show